# How can I run multiple instances of Telegram?

Tags: telegram, multiple-instances

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu.

I need to run multiple instances of desktop Telegram. I saw the answers in [How can I use multiple accounts with Telegram?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718912/how-can-i-use-multiple-accounts-with-telegram)

I do not understand how can I use the answer.

I extracted `tsetup.1.1.23.tar.xz`. and then opened the terminal and `cd` to that directory.

Also I created another administrator user named `atk2` with no password.

I tried running telegram as another user like this:

```
sudo -u user2 ./Telegram
```

but it does not work. I get

```
No protocol specified
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
./Telegram(_ZN14SignalHandlers8internal7HandlerEiP7siginfoPv+0x175)[0xe52725]
./Telegram(_ZN14SignalHandlers8internal12DumpCallbackERKN15google_breakpad18MinidumpDescriptorEPvb+0x2e)[0xe52f7e]
./Telegram(_ZN15google_breakpad16ExceptionHandler12GenerateDumpEPNS0_12CrashContextE+0x3d4)[0x10b83e4]
./Telegram(_ZN15google_breakpad16ExceptionHandler13SignalHandlerEiP7siginfoPv+0x97)[0x10b86f7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x13150)[0x7f6673f36150]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcb)[0x7f667360d0bb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16d)[0x7f667360ef5d]
./Telegram[0x1d6007e]
./Telegram(_ZN14QXcbConnectionC2EP19QXcbNativeInterfacebjPKc+0x97c)[0x1495bfc]
./Telegram(_ZN15QXcbIntegrationC1ERK11QStringListRiPPc+0x31e)[0x146971e]
./Telegram[0x14683bd]
./Telegram[0x1c3cb5d]
./Telegram[0x19810e5]
./Telegram[0x1981eb5]
./Telegram[0x1f1b63c]
./Telegram[0x198358c]
./Telegram[0x1657ad9]
./Telegram(_ZN11ApplicationC2ERiPPc+0x1e)[0xe5f13e]
./Telegram(main+0x8a)[0x8c94ea]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7f66735f71c1]
./Telegram[0x8e6b1d]
Aborted
```

I also tried

```
mkdir ~/.telegram2ndprofile
Telegram -many -workdir ~/.telegram2ndprofile
```

but I get this error in using telegram command.

```
# telegram -many -workdir ~/.telegram2ndprofile
usage: telegram [-ynsr] user [ttyname] [message...]
```

What should I do to run multiple telegram instances?

Comment: This `Telegram` should be `telegram`... I believe that link suggest you do `sudo -u otheruser ./Telegram` as another user to achieve that

Comment: You have to create another `profile` for the other user and use it like so `telegram -many -workdir ~/.telegram2ndprofile`

Comment: does it mean that I need to create some ubuntu user (from control panel like Window OS) and then run this command?

also if possible I look for a way that not need create another user.

Comment: @George . I create another account with name "user2".
 but I can not use the answer. would you please write a complete example?

Comment: also I have another question about this forum. I see a question at the top of my question "This question may already have an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/718912/how-can-i-use-multiple-accounts-with-telegram" ................ but, as I need more detail about using the answer, I asked this question. .............
does I need to put my question under that question?

Comment: Ok I learned it. first code to directory that Telegram file is there. second run "sudo -u user2 ./Telegram" in command window. but it does not run. and give an error

Comment: No protocol specified.......
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
.........a lot of text ........ Aborted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, I learned it. here is the detail of solution.

1. download tsetup.1.1.23.tar.xz
2. extract it.

   *it is better to copy "Telegram" file from extracted folder to "/home/youruser/" . because you can simply open the Terminal by Ctrl+Alt+T*.
3. open a Terminal on that folder.
4. create some folder for each Telegram account. for example:

> ```
> makedir ~/tel
> makedir ~/tel2
> ```

5. run the Telegram as

> ```
> ./Telegram -many -workdir ~/tel
> ```

6. for second user, open another Terminal and run Telegram as

> ```
> ./Telegram -many -workdir ~/tel2
> ```

**more option**

how can close the terminal without terminating the Telegram process?

I found the solution from here.
[How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)

> install "screen" application
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install screen
> ```
>
> Type screen in Terminal and Enter.
>       screen
>   Then start the Telegram.
>
> ```
> ./Telegram -many -workdir ~/tel
> ```
>
> return back to the terminal and
>
> Press Ctrl-A then Ctrl-D.

*Thanks for your helps.*